# Openerp act_window popsup a new window, but the main client disappear

Tags: odoo

I'm building a openerp customer module that in tree view, there is a button for each entry, when pressed, an act_window action will be triggered and open a new pops-up window, but at the same time, the main gtk client disappeared (only the pops-up remains). Also I have set the 'target' to 'new', but still the same. Any ideas?

client: gtk-6.0.3 on windows

server: 6.0.2 on debian 2.6.32

the xml looks like:

```
<field name="type">tree</field>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <tree string="Field Schema">
        <field name="field_name" />
        <field name="field_type" />
        <button name="edit" type="object" string="View and Edit" icon="gtk-go-forward" />
    </tree>
</field>
```

and the edit function to trigger looks like:

```
def edit(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    obj_name = some_fn_dynamic_get_obj_name_from_ids(ids)
    obj = self.pool.get(obj_name)
    if not obj:
        raise osv.except_osv('not supported')
    res_id = obj.create(....)
    ...
    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'name': 'View and Edit',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'res_model': obj_name,
        'res_id': res_id,
        'target': 'new',
        'context': context,
    }
```

Updated: after debug into the client's source, i finally found that: i make a typo: **nodestory** where the correct one should be **nodestroy**

```
    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        ...
        'context': context,
        'nodestroy': True,
    }
```

T_T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see anything obviously wrong. The `target` attribute is discussed in the [developer book](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_7_menu_action/7_2_actions.html#window-action). The only thing I can suggest would be to look for examples in the source code that use the `target` attribute and see how they differ from yours.

Comment: i've checked for several addons' source, but not find any differences. Also i've tested **gtk-client-6.1-win** and the **web-6.0.3-client**, the gtk client always has the same problem. But the web client is ok.

Comment: Do the other addons have the same problem as your code? If not, you can do the old trick of slowly eliminating all differences between the two sets of code. It's slow, but effective.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the client disappearing you need to add:
'nodestroy': True,